# All of a sudden firebase authentication not working! Unexpected response code 400

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My code was working perfectly fine for the last month didn't even touch it for a while for modifications or edits. But now, this problem came up and ruined my app for good. Please help me. The authentication is not working anymore and always fails. Here is my code

```
    package com.example.niki.responderview;

    import android.app.ActivityManager;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.StringBuilderPrinter;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener{

private Button buttonSignIn;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private TextView textViewSignUp;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    textViewSignUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignUp);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //if user is already login or not
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        //profile activity
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewUsers.class ));
    }

    buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void userLogin(){
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //does not give email address
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stop further execution
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //if password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stop execution
        return;
    }
    //if the requirements are satisfied
    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging In ..");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task){
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //user successfully registered
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewUsers.class ));
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to Log in. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });

}
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    if(view == buttonSignIn){
        //login user
        userLogin();
        //startActivity(new Intent(this, CurrentLocationActivity.class));
    }
    if(view == textViewSignUp){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class));
    }
}
```

}

I'm using a simple email and password for authentication it was also enabled in 
 the console.I don't know what to do, and I need to get it done.

Here's the error

```
    05-24 11:47:51.330 4162-2069/com.google.android.gms E/Herrevad: [276] 
    RemoteReportsRefreshChimeraService.a: want to send authenticated 
    request, but no Google account on device
    05-24 11:47:51.762 4162-4483/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [131] 
    BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for 
    https://android.googleapis.com/nova/herrevad/network_quality_info
    05-24 11:47:51.961 4162-17005/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [257] 
    BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for       
  https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?
    key=AIzaSyDdcFHJ9RTBrw1J0w2jtUEOhTHC7Jmi3_A
```

Comment: If `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` is failing, add `task.getException().getMessage()` to your Toast or log output to see why.

Answer (score 0):

In your Log its showing 'want to send authenticated request, but no Google account on device'. Is this crash is coming for every device. I prefer you test this in other devices.